# SQL TRIGGERS DATABASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have to implement a trigger in a table (Employee), the trigger should "trigger" when a simple employee gets a salary higher than the manager of his department.
And i have done this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER sal on EMPLOYEE

AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
as
declare @sal int;
declare @sal_mgr int;
declare @sal_manager TABLE(sal int)

SELECT @sal = salary FROM EMPLOYEE

SELECT @sal_mgr = salary FROM EMPLOYEE join Department on ssn = mgr_ssn where dno=dnumber

INSERT INTO @sal_manager values (@sal_mgr)

UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET salary = @sal_mgr-1 where salary >= @sal_mgr
```

But with this i only get the salary of 1 manager, not all i have in the different departments (its only allowed 1 manager for each department)

Comment: One employee only has one manager, no? Which other managers' salaries would be important then?

Comment: Each employee only have 1 manager, a manager have many employees.This code is getting always the same manager's salary, and comparing every employee with his salary. Not the manager of their department

Comment: I'm surprised that the above runs at all! You have multiple statements, but no begin - end structure.

Comment: Ok, so you run this trigger on the update/insert of 1 employee record, dealing with 1 employee, having 1 manager, who has 1 salary. Why would you want to do anything with any other manager, or their salaries then? You seem to want to get "all i have in the different departments"when you are only dealing with a single employee in a single department.

Comment: For example, i have to compare the salary from the employee in the dept. 1 with the dept's manager. the salary from the employee in the dept. 2 with the dept's manager. And so on.

Comment: But your trigger runs 1 time when you insert/update employee 1 from dept 1, and it runs again when you insert/update employee 2 from dept 2. I really cannot see why you want to compare to multiple managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 major problems with your code:

1. As I mentioned in a comment, you have multiple sql commands within the trigger (apparently), but there is no begin ... end structure to mark the start and end of the statements belonging to the trigger. Your code does not comply with mysql's [create trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) either.
2. None of the sql queries you included are run for the updated / inserted record, they run on the entire table. This explain why the code compares everything with the same manager: the last manager in the resultset of the query.

The inserted / updated record's fields can be accessed using the `NEW` keyword (see [examples in mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html))

```
SELECT @sal = salary FROM EMPLOYEE; -> not required, it is simply NEW.salary

SELECT @sal_mgr = salary FROM EMPLOYEE join Department on ssn = mgr_ssn where dno=dnumber;
```

The above should simply be (made a few assumptions which fields belong to which table because it is not clear from your code):

```
SELECT @sal_mgr = salary
FROM EMPLOYEE
inner join Department on EMPLOYEE.ssn = Department.mgr_ssn
where Department.dno=NEW.dnumber
```

You can rewrite all other queries based on the logic demonstrated above + pls use the proper mysql syntax for creating a trigger and using begin - end block.